# How to ask a good "Could X be built in Y:th century" question?

Tags: discussion, questions

(I feel this is a topic for a meta question. I hope You agree.)

A common type of WB question is the "Could device X be built in time/culture Y" reality checks.

While those questions are certainly valid, the answers generally focus on the supporting tech level and infrastructure of the era.

ie

Q: Could my time traveller build an assault rifle in medieval times?
A: No, metallurgy and manufacturing were not up to the task, and you could not get working ammo back then.

Well, if the time traveller had knowledge and resources enough he *could* "invent" modern metallurgy, blast caps and manufacturing methods. It certainly would not be belieaveble, but not technically *impossible*.

So, shouldn't we either:

- Recommend that such questions are rephrased as "What are the major
  obstacles if I want to build X in time/culture Y?" (Which would make
  the answers more clear)

or

- Define some canon "feasability levels" ie

  - Protagonist can build device only given common knowledge from his own time.
  - Protagonist can build device given exceptional knowledge from his own time.
  - Protagonist can build device given above plus lots of time and resources.
  - Protagonist might build device given above plus trust and backing from some major authority of the time/culture.
  - Protagonist can ony build device given ridiculous handwaving.

Answer (score 2):

I think an understanding of the common feasability levels is useful to those writing and reading the answers, without defining them in a formal way.

Comment: Yeah, I really weren't after a formal definition. More like a common frame. Sort of how any questions regarding "magic" is meaningless without some restriction of said magic.

Answer (score 2):

I think this just comes under the general, and rather common, problem of questions with fuzzy edges. You get a lot of questions where the end result has been thought of (ie I want an assault rifle in medieval times) but the question doesn't solidly describe what is fair game to achieve this.

I agree there are questions which need stricter definitions but I don't know that singling out the Xth century questions would help. Comments are probably the best way to get this across an an individual basis.

Answer (score 1):

Asking whether pinball machines could be built in the 15th century BCE and asking whether *a time traveller* could go to the 15th century BCE and build pinball machines there are *two very different questions*. The second question is essentially equivalent to asking whether a pinball machine factory could be built on the Svalbard islands: sure, why not, provided the funding is secured; it has nothing to do with the 15th century BCE.